# Any way to write a program or website to auto download audio from new youtube videos

Tags: youtube, automation

Any way to write a program or website to auto download audio from new youtube videos, and then that same program takes that file and uploads it to another website? I'm experienced in web scripting but pretty new to software development.

Answer (score 0):

You already have the program idea, which is a good start. [`youtube-dl`](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl) is a Python program. You can use it to download the audio from Youtube providing the URL. It can also only extract the audio link.

Any server side scripting languages (php, Python, js(nodejs), ...) can download files and upload files. Depends on which websites you want to upload the audios to, the implementations vary.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, i'd definitely like to run the program server side dunno why i didnt think of that lol, im going to be uploading the audio to sermon audio. How would i get that going as far as the script goes (preferably in node.js, php's fine too)

Answer (score 0):

I was writing this up when xhg posted. Good recommendations from him, here's a another possible route:

1. Use npm to get [node-ytdl](https://github.com/fent/node-ytdl). Run it with the `--filter audioonly` flag.
2. Use [transfer.sh](https://transfer.sh/) to upload the audio to your target.
3. [This post](https://superuser.com/questions/334272/how-to-run-a-command-after-an-already-running-existing-one-finishes) might be helpful in getting these processes to run sequentially.

Good luck!

Comment: alright i'll definitely try out both ways see what goes better.